# Unable to verifiy TCTL properties?

Tags: formal-verification, model-checking, formal-methods, ctl, uppaal

i built this template in UPPAAL 4.1 version. We can see in fig1, there exist a single path where agent can perform ReflexProcessing, but when i write given property

E<> not (MonitorAgent.ReflexProcessing)

Verifier satisfied it .

it shoud not be satisfied because a single path exist where ReflexProcessing done. kindly add your suggestion.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTNpi.jpg)

Comment: E<> stand for "there exist a path such that for some state on the path the subformula is valid". This is true in your model. From what I see, there exists a cycle without state ReflexProcessing (from yellow to green and back to yellow). Thus, even E[] should be valid."

Comment: the problem is that the property trivially holds in the initial state and says almost nothing about the rest of the model. I don't think you understand the property. Maybe you want  `E[] not MonitorAgent.ReflextProcessing` but I cannot guess because you did not state your intention.

Comment: sir, my intention is mention property"E<> not (MonitorAgent.ReflexProcessing)" should not be satisfied because in my model there is a single path where on some state ReflexProcessing occur,  but verifier satisfied it.